# Array of Checkboxes and input text fields in Limesurvey (2.0)

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

I want to create an array question that consists of checkboxes and short text input fields. Illustration:

```
 Fruits      bitter    sweet    salty      other                
 orange       cBox     cBox     cBox     inputText
 mango        cBox     cBox     cBox     inputText
   .           .        .        .           .
   .           .        .        .           .
   .           .        .        .           .
inputText     cBox     cBox     cBox     inputText
```

Till now i can create an "Array (Multi Flexi) (Numbers)" in the Checkbox variant but not with the needed text input fields. Regarding to the example a user should be able to enter a new fruit and describe it with an own taste.

It seems that there is no way to create new question types in Limesurvey 2.0. But i found a JavaScript based workaround for arranging [several single questions in one line](http://docs.limesurvey.org/Workarounds%3A+Question+design%2C+layout+and+templating#Multiple_question_types_in_array). When trying to adapt this script i found out that its not supporting the array question type (mentioned before) i need here.

Any ideas or different approaches to this aehm, challenge?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help or tricks that assist me solving this!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

1. Use an array of 'text' (existing question type in LimeSurvey)
2. Update needed 'input:text' : add a 'input:checkbox' in same cell (jquery is here)
3. Add a system for each of this checkbox : when this checkbox is checked : set input:text to Y, else set input:text to empty value

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).on('click',"#question{QID} :checkbox",function(){
       copiedid=$(this).data('copy');
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $("#"+copiedid).val('Y');
       }else{
           $("#"+copiedid).val('');
       }
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#question{QID}  tbody tr td:not(:last-child)').each(function(){
           var textinputid=$(this).find('input:text').attr('id');
           $(this).find('input:text').hide();
           $(this).append("<input type='checkbox' data-copy='"+textinputid+"' />");
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```